# google-java-format dependency syncing but not getting build.

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-java-format

I have added mavenCentral() in rootProject build script. But its giving below error while build. Any idea on this.

> You probably need to add a repository containing the '[com.google.googlejavaformat:google-java-format:1.5]' artifact in the
>   'build.gradle' of your root project.
>
> E.g.: 'buildscript { repositories { mavenCentral() }}'
>
> Note that included buildscripts (using 'apply
>   from') do not share their buildscript repositories with the underlying
>   project.
>
> You have to specify the missing repository explicitly in the
>   buildscript of the root project.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have jcenter() as a repository in your build.gradle(project)?

There is already exist
[Google Java Format in JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.google.googlejavaformat%3Agoogle-java-format)

Comment: is it jcenter? this link you provided going to maven repo

Comment: FYI. i have `mavenCentral()` in `build.gradle`. But `jcenter()` will not work under our proxy network. if its sure need to in `jcenter()`. i have to add it to host it in our local server.

Comment: Sorry you are right. Link was wrong. I have updated it.